# Ionic router push same page

Tags: ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, stenciljs

I'm using a **ionic stencil starter pwa** with **ionic router**.

I'm in a page and I need to push again that same page but with a different prop, so the page will be loaded from the start with the new prop and re-render.

I'm using

```
const navCtrl: HTMLIonRouterElement = await(this.nav as any).componentOnReady();
navCtrl.push("/pagename/" + prop + "/", "root");
```

if I'm in a different page, my push works correctly. the problem is when I'm in the same page, nothing happens.

Why this happens? there Is a way to  make it works?

Comment: Which ionic version are you working on? Is it version 3?

Comment: "@ionic/core": "^5.0.7",

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-properly-re-render-a-component-in-ionic-manually/97343/2

Comment: I've seen this post but this is an angular thread, instead I'm using stenciljs with vanilla js and the problem in the link isn't the same as mine :S

Comment: What is the thing you want to achieve exactly, maybe we could achieve in another way, but here there is a small unconplete peace of code and all what you need is to rerendet page, what is the purpose of re rending?

Comment: In the header of my pwa there is a button. if I click the button I push a page X with a certain prop.

The push action work in all the pages except when I'm already in page X.

I need to push page X with prop A if I am in page X with prop B...
I'm not able to push a page when I'm already in the page...

Comment: Did you try to preapre the page as function? For example in the page that have the prop add function dosomething(prop) { const pageProp = this.activatedRoute.....('id'); and do other things you need to achieve; } and after that yoy call the function inside ngOnInit(){this.dosomwthing('1')}; and on button click you trigger function dosomething('2') so the oage content get replaced.

Comment: I didn't tried this because I need to do different things at componentWillLoad, componentDidLoad etc so I don't think that change the logic page will be easy...

Comment: I got what you need, but i don't have the code. In order to get the way. Create an ionic sidemenu project, and you will file the logic you need inside html as i remember and the logic means that on each click on menu item you open the same page but with new page index and thus new page refreshed component properties.

Comment: My project it's already developed, I can't redo the work. I don't understand if ionic-router can't push a page when the page it's the active one or If I'm missing something.. but I cant redo the logic.

Comment: You didn't get me, give me some time like half an hour till i reach my computer and i'll send you what you need.